# What query syntax should I use for inserting records in an Oracle database?

Tags: c#, oracle, prepared-statement, sql-insert

I'm a beginner and trying to create a simple program in C# for inserting and updating records in an Oracle database. I have managed to successfully connect to the database but I'm getting an exception for my SQL statement which states that `(?)` symbol is not supported. Why am I getting this exception and how can I fix this?

My code is:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OracleConnection con = null;
    try
    {
        con = new OracleConnection();
        string constr = "Data source=XE; User ID=cloudester; Password=cloudester123;";
        if (con.State != ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            try
            {
                con.ConnectionString = constr;
                con.Open();
                //MessageBox.Show("Successfull connection");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Exception caught");
            }
        }

        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            string str = "Insert into EMP_DETAIL(EmpId, Name, Age)";
            str += "values (?,?,?)";

            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = Text;
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("EmpId", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = txtEmpId;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("Name", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = txtName;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("Age", OracleDbType.Int16)).Value = int.Parse(txtAge.Text);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    catch { ... }
}
```

Comment: I dont know what should I use instead of ?

Comment: I want to insert new record in oracle table. I have successfully connect database but Dont know how to insert record. I serach on internet but not found any working solution

Comment: i tried using Oraclecommand and it shows error in SQL satatement

Comment: You should use named parameters with `:` placeholders, like this `"Insert into EMP_DETAIL(EmpId, Name, Age) values(:EmpId, :Name, :Age)"`

Comment: Can you help me with simple insert program using OracleCommand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the named parameter for your command

```
string str = "Insert into EMP_DETAIL(EmpId, Name, Age) values (:EmpId, :Name, :Age)";
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.CommandText = str;  //cmd.CommandText = Text; not sure why did you use Text here
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("EmpId", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = txtEmpId;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("Name", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = txtName;
cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("Age", OracleDbType.Int16)).Value = int.Parse(txtAge.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 2):

As agent5566 [said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29796079/what-query-syntax-should-i-use-for-inserting-records-in-an-oracle-database#comment47720590_29796079), and from [`OracleCommand.Parameters` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

> When using named parameters in an SQL statement called by an
>   `OracleCommand` of `CommandType.Text`, you **must** precede the parameter name
>   with a colon (`:`)

Use them like;

```
using(var con = new OracleConnection(constr))
using(var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
   cmd.CommandText = @"Insert into EMP_DETAIL(EmpId, Name, Age)
                       values (:EmpId, :Name, :Age)";
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("EmpId", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = txtEmpId;
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("Name", OracleDbType.Varchar2)).Value = txtName;
   cmd.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("Age", OracleDbType.Int16)).Value = int.Parse(txtAge.Text);
   con.Open();
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

By the way, [`System.Data.OracleClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.OracleClient.aspx) has been marked as deprecated in .NET 4 version. You might wanna use [Oracle Data Provider for .NET](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/index-085163.html) instead.

As an alternative, [DataDirect](https://www.progress.com/products/datadirect-connect/adonet-providers/data-sources/oracle) and [DevArt](https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/) also have their own oracle providers for .NET.

Comment: for accuracy:  It is unclear what Oracle Provider he is using ;)

Comment: @agent5566 Exactly. I just added as an additional information :)